# Lips detection in Opencv using AAM

Tags: ios, opencv

Im new to iOS development and Opencv. And I want to detect Exactly Lips location and its width and height. I have used those haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml file but result was not satisfying. So If any one could give me some idea about AAM process then it will be really helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code  chapters 6 & 7

( book is partly on google.books)

2 others i know of:

http://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/

http://code.google.com/p/asmlib-opencv

and ofc, STASM, http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using OpenCV to detect lips location, why not using Core Image?
Using cascade boosting is computationally heavy. I bet the performance suffering some 'speed' isn't?

By using Core Image:

```
CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]]; //You can adjust accuracy here
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
{
    if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
    {
        //Access mouse position using 'faceFeature.mouthPosition'
        //track maybe?
        //use Lucas Kanade tracker or Fast Corner tracker
    }
}
```

Comment: This code for coreimage library. But this code not working for AAM opencv framework. Using coreimage library we can get only two eyes and a mouth with fixed position but in the case if anybody loughing or annoying then proper mouth width and height can get.

Comment: Yes that's true. You need to train lots of data using Neural Network or whatever machine learning and using descriptor that is invariance towards many cases. Even you can get low false positive, the speed of detection will be terrible. This is quite 'hella' of work need to do here in compromising between speed and accuracy